# Does a process started by C# Process.Start() inherit ErrorMode?

Tags: c#, process

If you call the WinAPI function CreateProcess (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), you can choose if the new process should inherit the ErrorMode of the caller.

My question is if a process started with the C# Process.Start-method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) inherits the ErrorMode of the caller, of if it gets the default ErrorMode?

I can't seem to find this in the documentation on MSDN...

Comment: Where is it written that `you can choose if the new process should inherit the ErrorMode of the caller.`? I didn't find it.

Comment: The CreateProcess function takes an argument `dwCreationFlags` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx), in which `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE` can be set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you watch with resharper/ilspy and/or you watch the sources of .NET you'll see that in `Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)` all the magic happens.

`num2` is the variable that contains the `dwCreationFlags`. Your flag isn't visible anywhere. Sometimes  `StartWithCreateProcess` sets the 0x8000000 (`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`) (if the `CreateNoWindow` parameter is set) and the 0x400 (`CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`) (if the system is NT based) flags, but that's all.

Comment: I'm not really sure if you answered the question. Do you mean that only those two flags can be set by `StartInfo`? I know that I can't choose the value of `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE` when using `Process.Start()`, I'm wondering if it is set or not? Or do you mean that it is not set?

Comment: @Findus I'm telling you that in the code of `Process.Start` those flags aren't set, and the only flags it uses (sometimes) are those two.